# AngularJS $scope not updating after using RANGE Slider

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The scenario is that when I **click the buttons first**, the **scope updates**.

But the moment when I **use the slider**, the buttons will **no longer update the scope/UI** .

Here is the code

Controller

```
$scope.restaurantsInRadius = function(radius) {
    $scope.radius=parseInt(radius);
    radius = parseInt(radius);
    var markers_in_area = [];

    circle.setRadius(radius);
    removeMarkers();
    for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        if ( google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(usersLatLng, gmarkers[i].position) < radius ) {
            gmarkers[i].setMap($scope.map);
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<ion-view view-title="Map" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
<ion-content class="padding">
    <div style="height: 100%">

        <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>

        <div style=" text-align: left ">   
            <br/>
            <button class="button button-assertive button-small" ng-click="showAllMarkers()">All</button>
            <button class="button button-assertive button-small" ng-click="restaurantsInRadius(100)">100m</button>
            <button class="button button-assertive button-small" ng-click="restaurantsInRadius(1000)">1km</button>
            <button class="button button-assertive button-small" ng-click="restaurantsInRadius(3000)">3km</button> 

            <span>Distance: {{radius}} meters</span>
            <div class="range" style="height: 100%">
              <i class="icon ion-minus-round"></i>
              <input type="range" name="radius" value="100"
                     min="100" max="3000" ng-model="radius" step="50"
                     ng-change="restaurantsInRadius(radius)" />
              <i class="icon ion-plus-round"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I call the restaurantsInRadius() by ng-click for the buttons, and ng-change for the slider.

Comment: you can't use ` $scope.radius=parseInt(radius);` and `ng-model="radius"` at the same time with `ng-change`;  every time that the function fires and runs the `parseInt` it will cause a change, causing the `ng-model` to fire the change, etc... you are likely seeing an error in the console about that.  You probably need your buttons to call a different function to set `$scope.radius` and then call `restaurantsInRadius`, so your slider doesn't crash itself.

Comment: Thank you sir for your insight. I changed the ng-model of range to 'currValue' so that the $scope.radius won't be touched.